Using Neural Networks Transformer
I was doing Neural Networks exercises for my upcoming test and I skipped the last classes, so I can't figure out how to solve these transformer problems. Unfortunately, asking the teacher, didn't really work out either...
He gave us the following code:
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras 
from keras import layers

Simple keras implementation of a transformer encoder block
class TransformerBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, rate=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.att = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)
        self.ffn = keras.Sequential(
            [layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu"), layers.Dense(embed_dim),]
        )
        self.layernorm1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dropout1 = layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, inputs):
        attn_output = self.att(inputs, inputs)
        attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(inputs + attn_output)
        ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)
        ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output)
        return self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)

Use tf.keras.layers.Embedding layers
To create an initial embedding for a categorical variable.
To create a positional embedding (to be added to another already existing sequence embedding):

Define maxLen, the maximum length of your sequences. Let x be a batch of sequences of k-dimensionalvectors (embeddings).

batch_size, l, k = x.shape


class positionEmb(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, max_len, output_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.posEmb = layers.Embedding(input_dim=max_len, output_dim=output_dim)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        length = tf.shape(inputs)[1]
        batchSize = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
        positions = tf.range(length)
        position_embeddings =  self.posEmb(positions)
        position_embeddings = tf.broadcast_to(position_embeddings,
                                              [batchSize,length,self.output_dim])
        return position_embeddings

positionEmbedding = positionEmb(1000,3)
x = np.ones((2,4,3))
pos =  positionEmbedding(x)
pos

Which gave the following output:
\<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 4, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array(\[\[\[ 0.0496983 , -0.01929103,  0.04586143\],
\[ 0.03327824, -0.04059364,  0.01518938\],
\[-0.02593035, -0.00701543,  0.03312309\],
\[-0.04562145, -0.02720568,  0.01570702\]\],

       [[ 0.0496983 , -0.01929103,  0.04586143],
        [ 0.03327824, -0.04059364,  0.01518938],
        [-0.02593035, -0.00701543,  0.03312309],
        [-0.04562145, -0.02720568,  0.01570702]]], dtype=float32)>

The 1st problem is to use a transformer in the given dataset. I already wrote some things, to explain better how the data looked.
dfwindTrain = pd.read_csv('wdTrain.csv')
dfwindVal = pd.read_csv('wdVal.csv')
dfwindTest = pd.read_csv('wdTest.csv')


print("Train")
print(dfwindTrain.head())
print("Columns:", dfwindTrain.columns)

print("Val")
print(dfwindVal.head())
print("Columns:", dfwindVal.columns)

print("Test")
print(dfwindTest.head())
print("Columns:", dfwindTest.columns)

Which gave me:
Train
p (mbar)  T (degC)  Tpot (K)  Tdew (degC)  rh (%)  VPmax (mbar)  
0    996.50     -8.05    265.38        -8.78    94.4          3.33  
1    996.62     -8.88    264.54        -9.77    93.2          3.12  
2    996.84     -8.81    264.59        -9.66    93.5          3.13  
3    996.99     -9.05    264.34       -10.02    92.6          3.07  
4    997.46     -9.63    263.72       -10.65    92.2          2.94

VPact (mbar)  VPdef (mbar)  sh (g/kg)  H2OC (mmol/mol)  rho (g/m\*\*3)  
0          3.14          0.19       1.96             3.15       1307.86  
1          2.90          0.21       1.81             2.91       1312.25  
2          2.93          0.20       1.83             2.94       1312.18  
3          2.85          0.23       1.78             2.85       1313.61  
4          2.71          0.23       1.69             2.71       1317.19

wv (m/s)  max. wv (m/s) wind direction  
0      0.21           0.63              S  
1      0.25           0.63              S  
2      0.18           0.63              S  
3      0.10           0.38              E  
4      0.40           0.88              S  
Columns: Index(\['p (mbar)', 'T (degC)', 'Tpot (K)', 'Tdew (degC)', 'rh (%)',
'VPmax (mbar)', 'VPact (mbar)', 'VPdef (mbar)', 'sh (g/kg)',
'H2OC (mmol/mol)', 'rho (g/m\*\*3)', 'wv (m/s)', 'max. wv (m/s)',
'wind direction'\],
dtype='object')
Val
p (mbar)  T (degC)  Tpot (K)  Tdew (degC)  rh (%)  VPmax (mbar)  
0    994.77      6.07    279.64         2.92   80.20          9.40  
1    994.54      9.88    283.48         4.18   67.58         12.20  
2    994.35     13.53    287.15         5.79   59.42         15.53  
3    994.04     15.43    289.08         6.84   56.50         17.56  
4    993.88     15.54    289.21         7.58   59.02         17.68

VPact (mbar)  VPdef (mbar)  sh (g/kg)  H2OC (mmol/mol)  rho (g/m\*\*3)  
0          7.54          1.86       4.73             7.58       1237.52  
1          8.24          3.95       5.17             8.29       1220.23  
2          9.23          6.30       5.79             9.28       1204.01  
3          9.92          7.64       6.23             9.98       1195.39  
4         10.44          7.25       6.56            10.50       1194.50

wv (m/s)  max. wv (m/s) wind direction  
0      0.74           1.68              O  
1      0.58           1.12              O  
2      0.70           1.46              S  
3      0.92           1.84              S  
4      0.30           0.56              E  
Columns: Index(\['p (mbar)', 'T (degC)', 'Tpot (K)', 'Tdew (degC)', 'rh (%)',
'VPmax (mbar)', 'VPact (mbar)', 'VPdef (mbar)', 'sh (g/kg)',
'H2OC (mmol/mol)', 'rho (g/m\*\*3)', 'wv (m/s)', 'max. wv (m/s)',
'wind direction'\],
dtype='object')
Test
p (mbar)  T (degC)  Tpot (K)  Tdew (degC)  rh (%)  VPmax (mbar)  
0    980.12     18.27    293.11        13.23    72.4         21.03  
1    980.66     17.85    292.64        13.14    73.9         20.48  
2    981.13     16.65    291.39        13.00    79.0         18.98  
3    981.43     15.85    290.56        12.92    82.7         18.04  
4    981.71     15.09    289.78        12.86    86.5         17.18

VPact (mbar)  VPdef (mbar)  sh (g/kg)  H2OC (mmol/mol)  rho (g/m\*\*3)  
0         15.22          5.80       9.72            15.53       1164.71  
1         15.13          5.34       9.65            15.43       1167.07  
2         14.99          3.99       9.56            15.28       1172.53  
3         14.92          3.12       9.51            15.20       1176.18  
4         14.86          2.32       9.47            15.14       1179.64

wv (m/s)  max. wv (m/s) wind direction  
0      2.57           3.64              S  
1      2.47           3.62              S  
2      1.72           2.64              S  
3      1.40           2.04              S  
4      1.67           2.38              E  
Columns: Index(\['p (mbar)', 'T (degC)', 'Tpot (K)', 'Tdew (degC)', 'rh (%)',
'VPmax (mbar)', 'VPact (mbar)', 'VPdef (mbar)', 'sh (g/kg)',
'H2OC (mmol/mol)', 'rho (g/m\*\*3)', 'wv (m/s)', 'max. wv (m/s)',
'wind direction'\],
dtype='object')

The second exercise is similar, but it says to use a transformer to predict the temperature for all the next 6 hours in the same dataset.
I watched some youtube videos to try to understand, but I'm only supposed to use tensorflow and keras to solve this, so I haven't been able to figure it out yet...
Any help would be appreciated!
I tried to do it by myself and failed miserably. Also tried chatGPT, but it also didn't work very well...

You need to clearly describe the problem, to me it is not clear what are you having problems with...

I don't even know where to begin to solve this...

To solve what? You did not describe the problem at all, we do not know what you have to "solve".

Maybe that's the problem, because that's all that was said on the exercises...
